.NET - Sending an email via EWS using the logged in user's credentials
We use a process on a Windows application where a user will trigger an automated email from themselves to another user. At the moment an Outlook session is opened and an email is sent that way, but we occasionally have users get this error that require an Office reinstall.
Instead, we decided to look into sending the email via Exchange since SMTP emails don't go into the sent folder. I found this answer where point #2 caught my eye. Would someone be able to elaborate on how to utilize this?
For context, my code currently looks like this:
Public Sub SendEmail(Sender As String, Name As String, Recipient As String, Subject As String, Body As String, Optional CC As String = Nothing)
Dim Service As New ExchangeService With {
    .Url = New Uri("https://example.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml")
}
Dim Message As New EmailMessage(Service) With {
    .Subject = Subject,
    .Body = New MessageBody(Body)
}
Message.ToRecipients.Add(Recipient)
Message.SendAndSaveCopy()
End Sub

I get a No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it error currently. Having the line Service.AutodiscoverUrl(Sender) after the service creation comes back with an Autodiscover blocked a potentially insecure redirection error. I don't have access to the user's password, but the Windows account they are on is tied to their email.
Any resources or help would be appreciated, thank you.
